# nan returned using long doubles with math.h functions

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn about floating point precision in C.  I came across this problem while experimenting with promotion and demotion in math.h functions.

In the following program, I get a -nan for the first equation using long doubles and a result for the second.  I do not understand why.  If `pow(x,y)` with long doubles returns a -nan, why does `(pow(x,y) - z)` with long doubles return the correct result?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* equation from xkcd: e to the pi minus pi is 19.999099979 */
int main(void)
{
    printf("f  %#.9f\n",
           pow(2.71828182846F, 3.14159265359F));
    printf("f  %#.9f\n",
           pow(2.71828182846F, 3.14159265359F) - 3.14159265359F);
    printf("d  %#.9lf\n",
           pow(2.71828182846, 3.14159265359));
    printf("d  %#.9lf\n",
           pow(2.71828182846, 3.14159265359) - 3.14159265359);
    printf("ld %#.9Lf\n",
           pow(2.71828182846L, 3.14159265359L));
    printf("ld %#.9Lf\n",
           pow(2.71828182846L, 3.14159265359L) - 3.14159265359L);
    return 0;
}

output:
f  23.140692448
f  19.999099707
d  23.140692633
d  19.999099979
ld -nan
ld 19.999099979
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour if your format specifiers do not match the data types of the arguments you pass to `printf` <sup>(a)</sup>.

If you were using a decent compiler, it would warn you of this:

```
myprog.c:15:12: warning: format '%Lf' expects argument of type
    'long double', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
     printf("ld %#.9Lf\n",
            ^
```

The solution is to ensure the argument *is* of the correct type to match the format either by casting:

```
printf("ld %#.9Lf\n", (long double)pow(2.71828182846L, 3.14159265359L));
```

or, better yet:

```
printf("ld %#.9Lf\n", powl(2.71828182846L, 3.14159265359L));
```

The latter would be preferred since the former may <sup>(b)</sup> involve loss of precision.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> See `C11 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions /9` for the "undefined behaviour" specification:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

and `/7` of that same section for the type requirement of `%Lf`:

> **`L`** Specifies that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to a ***long double*** argument.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> ***May,*** because the standard states that each "lesser" floating point type is a subset of the next "greater" type. Since subset (as opposed to proper subset) means "lesser *or equal to* the superset", it's possible for double and long double to be exactly the same underlying type.

However, it's safer to assume that it *is* a proper subset since you don't really lose anything in that assumption.

Comment: The `pow` function returns a result of type `double`. You can convert the result to `long double`, but for most purposes it would be better to call `powl`, which return a result of type `long double`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I see now.  I understood pow demoted the long doubles to make the calculation but forgot the result returned is also a double.  It works with the minus portion of the equation because the pow result is then promoted in that calculation.  Thanks for replying.  And now off to learn more about casting :)

Comment: Is it worth mentioning `<tgmath.h>`, or is that piece of black magic best left in the shadows?

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined behavior as paxdiablo pointed out. Here's what my compiler shows as an example of the warning he mentions:

```
gcc main.c -o main
.main.c:10:24: warning: format specifies type 'long double' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
    printf("ld %#.9Lf\n", pow(2.71828182846L, 3.14159265359L));
               ~~~~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               %#.9f
1 warning generated.
```

And here's an example where NaN doesn't show up:

```
$ ./main 
f  23.140692448
f  19.999099707
d  23.140692633
d  19.999099979
ld -0.000000000
ld 19.999099979
```